# Loopback ACL: Create a User with a Role

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I struggling to decipher the documentation on creating a user with an acl role. I'd like to create 2 roles "admin" and "user" similar to what the documentation states. However, I cannot find the API documentation for Role.create. Nor does the given example make any sense to me. I'd then like to create a user via ONLY the REST API and then assign the user either admin or user roles. This seems simple but I'm scratching my head. Can someone provide some guidance on how to get started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this area of the docs needs some work, and I'm working to improve it as soon as possible.  We're also going to clean up and improve the API docs.

The Role model inherits all of the CRUD methods from the base DataModel object: http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#datamodel-new-datamodel.  So, for example, Role.create() is the same as DataModel.create()

The same is true for the REST API.  The Role REST API is documented here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Role+REST+API.  You'll notice that each endpoint in this doc links to the "Model REST API" article which provides more detail.

-Rand

Technical Writer, StrongLoop

Comment: Do I have to configure the app to create the "roles" endpoint? Don't see it out of the box. If I create a new Role, can I use the acl command line tool & specify the new role by name? I'm having a real hard time grasping the concepts here. I'm relatively new to Node (which is why maybe I'm leaning more on the acl cmd line or rest apis). All the sample apps and documentation use the dynamic role (owner, everyone, etc). I have to have an admin role that has access to the data regardless of the owner. Love the acl tool to remove a lot of the complexity but it just doesnt seem to do what i need.

Comment: I posted the answer I was looking for. I didn't see anywhere in the docs that explicitly indicated that certain models are not public but now that I see it, I understand why its not public by default. Make sense...just wasnt apparent without some digging.

Comment: Would also be nice to have an example of what the role json body should be when using the Role REST api. Or a link to the Role model schema that must be used.

Answer (score 4):

Ah found it. In the models.json, you have to make the role model public in order for it to be exposed as a Rest endpoint. Once defined and acl's configured, you should probably set it back to false.

```
...
"role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true,
    "options": {
      "base": "Role",
      "relations": {
        "principals": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "roleMapping",
          "foreignKey": "roleId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
...
```

Comment: where is this  models.json?

Comment: in npm_modules/loopback/common/models

Answer (score 2):

You can also find sample usages at https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/test/role.test.js